# Why is it not possible to use foreach in async function?

Tags: swift, asynchronous

Why can't I use foreach when using async functions? I always thought they just do the same thing.

```
 let query = try? await store.collection("feedposts").getDocuments()
 let documents = query?.documents ?? []
```

This works perfectly:

```
for document in documents {
            try? await store.collection("feedposts").document(document.documentID).collection("locked").document(uid).delete()
        }
```

While this doesn't:

```
documents.forEach { document in
            try? await store.collection("feedposts").document(document.documentID).collection("locked").document(uid).delete()
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for x in y` is a language feature and executes in the current scope. So the `await` is also executed in the current scope.

But the [`forEach` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/foreach(_:)) is, well, a *method* that takes a specific argument:

```
func forEach(_ body: (Self.Element) throws -> Void) rethrows
```

You pass it a block, and if you look at the signature of `body` you see that it's lacking the `async` keyword. The block is thus not (guaranteed to be) executed in an async environment. But you can only use `await` in an `async` scope, which `body` is not guaranteeing to the compiler and it thus doesn't allow you to use `await` here.

If you want a `forEach` *method* that supports async/await, you need to [implement it yourself](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/async-and-concurrent-forEach-and-map/). Whether Swift is going to provide an async `forEach` is [debated in the Swift project](https://forums.swift.org/t/do-we-want-foreach/56929).