# Swift How to wait until a specific condition is met

Tags: swift, concurrency, nscondition

I've looked through just about every question on this topic I could find but I've had little success. I need to run a function on an array of actors conforming to a specific actor protocol. Because these are actors, I need an async call. But I also need to run these functions in a specific order, and I'm not going to describe how I get the order, just suffice it to say that I have it. I am also using the following `asyncForEach` function, though I'm open to not doing this.

```
extension Sequence {
    func asyncForEach (
        _ operation: @escaping (Element) async -> Void
    ) async {
        // A task group automatically waits for all of its
        // sub-tasks to complete, while also performing those
        // tasks in parallel:
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for element in self {
                group.addTask {
                    await operation(element)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have some protocol

```
protocol ProtocolConformingActors: Actor {
    func bar() async throws
}
```

This leads me to running my function

```
func foo() async throws {
    let actorsAndOrders: [Int: ProtocolConformingActors] = [1:actor1, 2:actor2, 3:actor3]

    // Get order
    var orders: [Int] = []
    for entry in actorsAndOrders {
        orders.append(entry.key)
    }
    orders.sort()

    // Run func
    await orders.asyncForEach { order in
        let actor = actorsAndOrders[order]

        try await actor?.bar()
    }
}
```

And this is where the problem occurs. Like I mentioned above, these calls need to be async because `bar()` is modifying isolated properties on each actor. Because in order to make this happen, I need to use the asyncForEach, but as I understand it, the `asyncForEach` loop sets up and runs each function `bar()` in parallel. But they need to be run in order.

Is there a way I can make each thread wait until a condition is met?

I was thinking I might be able to  use the condition `orders[0] == order` and when `bar()` is done running, remove the first entry from the `orders` array, which could make it tell the next thread it can wake up again.

But while the apple documentation seems to indicate that there is a `wait(until:)` function on `NSCondition`, I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: If running the `bar`s one after another is what you actually want, why did you write `asyncForEach` which does exactly the opposite (running the `bar`s in parallel)? You should be able to just use a regular for loop to loop over `orders` and await `bar`.

Comment: I get the following error if I try that: `Cannot pass function of type '(Int) async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type`

Comment: Are you using the `forEach` function? Don't use that. Use a *regular for loop*. `for order in orders { try await actorsAndOrders[order]?.bar() }` Does that work?

Comment: And that fixed the error! Thank you! Why did that work though, what is the difference between `for order in orders` and `orders.forEach{ order in ...`

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73717396/5133585)

Comment: Fascinating! Thank you Sweeper

Comment: @TinyTim I think you might find this useful: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/23f6c9f44fa7cebe12c2f029ea36586d

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you so much! I feel like I've gained a lot of strength in certain parts of swift and I recognize I'm not entirely incompetent anymore but theres still a lot of things that feel very basic that I'm lacking. Walking through the steps like you have makes it very clear what's changing and why things are changing. I think I can use this to amend other parts of my code as well, thank you!